# Html.ValidationMessageFor custom message always show

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliverySchedule.d_date, "Please fill up.", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

for my validation. However it keep showing on page load.
after adding the css below. it disappear on first load but when i submit the form with empty field. The message does not come out.

```
.field-validation-valid
{display: none;}
```

**Javascript ref also added**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult ArrangeDelivery() {
        var list = service.GetNotDeliveryScheduleList();
        return View(list);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ArrangeDelivery(OrderViewModel model)
    {


        var result = service.SetDeliverySchedule(model);
        if (result==true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ArrangeDelivery");
        }
        var list = service.GetNotDeliveryScheduleList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliverySchedule.d_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control bootdatepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliverySchedule.d_date, "Please fill up.", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

**View model**

```
 public class OrderViewModel
{

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        DeliveryScheduleList = new List<DeliverySchedule>();
        DeliveryPartList = new List<DeliveryPart>();
    }

    public List<DeliverySchedule> DeliveryScheduleList { get; set; }
    public DeliverySchedule DeliverySchedule { get; set; }
    public List<DeliveryPart> DeliveryPartList { get; set; }
}
```

**Actual Model with DB first**

```
 public partial class DeliverySchedule
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DL_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> datum { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> zeit { get; set; }
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string postal { get; set; }
    public string person_look_for { get; set; }
    public string contact_look_for { get; set; }
    public string PO_Number { get; set; }
    public string staff { get; set; }
    public string invoice { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public string d_type { get; set; }
    public string d_arranged { get; set; }
    public string i_return { get; set; }
    public string d_done { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> d_date { get; set; }
    public string d_time { get; set; }
    public string d_by { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DO_Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your GET method and the model

Comment: Hi updated. i did not indicate `Require` in my model as not all place need to fill up this.

Comment: Just delete the 2nd parameter and use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DeliverySchedule.d_date, new { @class = "text-danger" })`. If you want a specific error message when invalid, add it to your validation attribute

Comment: But i don't want this field to be `Required` as this field is not mandatory at other page. If i add that to my model. My other form will not be able to submit without entering this

Comment: Then use a view model for each page! (and you still have not shown the model property)

Comment: Hi stephen, `@required = "required"`  i add this to editor and it works. A dumb solution. However i will still upload my model for a better solution. give me awhile

Comment: Well it makes no sense if you don't need validation you can simply remove @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DeliverySchedule.d_date .. OR u need to check some other validation than required ??